# Can a mapper know how many mappers are running?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

In a hadoop Map-Reduce framework, when an application is running, is it possible to know the number of workers running in the program. The number of workers is same as the number of file splits so in other words, is it possible to know the number of file splits dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total number of map tasks and reducer tasks that make up the job can be queried via the `mapred.map.tasks` and `mared.reduce.tasks` configuration properties (once your job has been submitted).

If you look through the source, you can see this being set in `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient:784` (and yes it's the same number of splits)

```
// Create the splits for the job
LOG.debug("Creating splits at " + fs.makeQualified(submitSplitFile));
int maps;
if (job.getUseNewMapper()) {
  maps = writeNewSplits(context, submitSplitFile);
} else {
  maps = writeOldSplits(job, submitSplitFile);
}
job.set("mapred.job.split.file", submitSplitFile.toString());
job.setNumMapTasks(maps); // here is where mapred.map.tasks is set
```

Comment: will this program give the number of mappers and reducers running in the program? where will we write this program?